# Netbeans 8 like AutoComplete in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, netbeans, autocomplete, intellisense, netbeans-8

In Netbeans auto complete suggests partially matching words e.g. `x.fb` will also suggest `x.FooBar`.

Can I replicate that with a smaller plugin in Visual Studio 2013?

Resharper is resource hungry (and not free) and will be an overkill for only extending Intellisense just that much.

Comment: For which language? There are many plugins available, C++ e.g. Visual Assist.

Comment: You have already expressed a disliking of ReSharper so I will keep it brief, but yes ReSharper does exactly that using the Navigate to File command.